# Why doesn't wp_update_post() update the post_status field?

Tags: post-status, wp-update-post, scheduled-posts

I'm using this bit to insert/update a custom post type from the front-end. The date is set from a custom jquery datepicker.

```
    if (strtotime($date) < strtotime('tomorrow')) {
            $newpostdata['post_status'] = 'publish';
    } elseif (strtotime($date) > strtotime('today')) {
            $newpostdata['post_status'] = 'future';
            $newpostdata['post_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
    }

    if ('insert' == $operation) {
        $err = wp_insert_post($newpostdata, true);
    } elseif ('edit' == $operation) {
        $newpostdata['ID'] = $post_id;
        $err = wp_update_post($newpostdata);
    }
```

**This works** when first publishing the post, setting it correctly as `publish` or `future`, with the correct date.

**This doesn't work** when editing the same post, neither from `publish` to `future` nor the other way around. Everything else is properly updated, except for the post status/<strike>future_date</strike>.

**UPDATE Oct. 9th** 
I'm starting to think this might be a bug, [so i started a conversation at the wp-hackers mailing list](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2012-October/044511.html), about this. There's some fresh install test results on the link.

---

**OTHER FAILED ATTEMPTS:**

i've tried leaving `post_status` decisions to `wp_insert_post()` using:

```
elseif ('edit' == $operation) {
        $newpostdata['post_status'] = '';
        $newpostdata['ID'] = $post_id;
        $err = wp_update_post($newpostdata);
    }
```

And this sets the post status to `draft` while maintaning the requested dates.

I've also tried calling [`wp_transition_post_status()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) again (it's called once inside wp_insert_post()):

```
elseif ('edit' == $operation) {
        $newpostdata['ID'] = $post_id;
        $err = wp_update_post($newpostdata);
        wp_transition_post_status($old_status, $status, $post_id);
    }
```

but that also didn't seem to work.

I'm running out of ideas here. Any clues?

Comment: I am confused, When editing the post, and setting it to future, the post date doesn't get updated?

Comment: post date gets updated, but post status doesn't. So if I publish a post today, and then set it to `future` with a date three days from today, the date gets changed, but post_status is still `publish`, instead of `future`

Comment: Ok, this just in: if I strip out the post_status before updating the post, it then gets reverted to `draft` and still appears in the admin panel as scheduled. So it works, but that still doesn't answer why I can't revert it to `future`.

Comment: Are you doing this as logged in user with sufficient capabilities? Data manipulation functions tend to check if user is actually allowed to perform it.

Comment: Yes, i'm doing it as an network admin, and also as a "custom" user role.

Comment: Hey, Moraleida, you forgot to close the case here too ;)

Comment: Right you are, brother @brasofilo. I'll post it here shortly. :)

Comment: And if I may suggest something: clean up the question, so Q and A go straight to the point. Saudações!

Comment: I had a similar problem and the cause of it was that the `post_status` parameter was more than 20 characters long. https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status Hope it helps!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer couldn't be simpler.

As pointed out by [Otto](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2232/otto) at the wp-hackers list, problem was me not setting `post_date_gmt` when using `wp_update_post()`.

Final code looks like this:

```
if ( $post_date < strtotime( "tomorrow" ) ) {
        $status = 'publish';    
        $newpostdata['post_status'] = $status;
        $newpostdata['post_date'] = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s',  $post_date );

        // Also pass 'post_date_gmt' so that WP plays nice with dates
        $newpostdata['post_date_gmt'] = gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_date );

    } elseif ( $post_date > strtotime( 'today' ) ) {
        $status = 'future';    
        $newpostdata['post_status'] = $status;
        $newpostdata['post_date'] = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_date );

        // Also pass 'post_date_gmt' so that WP plays nice with dates
        $newpostdata['post_date_gmt'] = gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_date );
    }

    if ('insert' == $operation) {
        $err = wp_insert_post($newpostdata, true);
    } elseif ('edit' == $operation) {
        $newpostdata['ID'] = $post_id;
        $err = wp_update_post($newpostdata);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I also tried the above code using `wp_update_post()` , but it doesn't work well with WordPress 3.9, it makes `post_status` empty and deleted all custom fields. I therefore created a custom query using the `wpdb` class. I hope this will work for all of you:

```
$wpdb->query( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_status = 'draft' WHERE ID = %d", 
        $post_id 
    )
);
```

and this worked well on my localhost and hosting too.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you don't mind the modifications. I fixed the prepare statement.

Answer (score 1):

We update the post status all the time, here is an example of how we allow users (on the front end editor that was built) to "pause" ads by changing them to draft:

```
if ($action == 'pause') {
        $my_post = array();
        $my_post['ID'] = $aid;
        $my_post['post_status'] = 'draft';
        wp_update_post($my_post);
        $action_msg = __('Ad has been paused', 'mytheme');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> $newpostdata['post_date'] = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s',  $post_date );

This will return fisrt intial date of php 1970, use strtotime to convert string to time

> $newpostdata['post_date'] = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 
>   strtotime($post_date) );

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 
`"edit_date" => true`
in wp_update_post array

Answer (score 0):

Not the OP's issue, but as a notable point of reference for others finding their way here researching a similar issue where `wp_update_post()` doesn't update `post_status` ...

As @adrianthedev noted above in a comment on the OP, note that the maximum length of a custom post status is 20 chars.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_status/#comment-3927

When 20 chars are exceeded, you are able to register the custom post status using `register_post_status()`, but currently unable to set a post as using it with `wp_update_post()`, at least as of WordPress v5.5.1